# Loop Quantum Gravity vs Polymer Quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, quantum-gravity, quantization, loop-quantum-gravity

What is the linkage between [Loop Quantum Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) and the approach of the [Polymer Quantization](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=polymer+quantization)?
I know you get a lattice using the correct polymer representation, so that's a good toy model for the full theory of LQG, but what are the assumptions to justify this as toy model?
What is that we are neglecting/suppressing of the full LQG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer quantization was inspired by Loop Quantization from LQG. It's an attempt to use the same methods that successfully worked for gravity in the LQG context and apply them to ordinary QFT on Minkowski background.

A disclaimer: I claim that Loop Quantization was successful when applied to gravity, because it produces a self-consistent mathematical model. I do not claim that this model is physically successful, that is, I do not claim that it has had any experimental confirmation whatsoever.

The basic idea of Polymer quantization is to take an uncountable set of physical modes (usually taken to be plane waves parameterized by the 3-momentum $\vec{p}$) and construct objects closely resembling *cylindrical functions* from Loop Quantization. I will simply call them cylindrical functions here.

A cylindrical function consists of:

1. A finite subset of the (uncountably infinite) set of allowed modes. We call this the support set of the cylindrical function.
2. A function on the *finite dimensional* subset of field configurations spanned by the modes.

A cylindrical function can be reinterpreted as a functional on the space of field configurations, if we assume that it simply *doesn't depend* on the (uncountably infinite number of) remaining degrees of freedom.

Let's construct an explicit example. I'll choose an arbitrary pair of 3-vectors $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$, and an arbitrary function $\psi(f_1, f_2)$ of 2 real variables with appropriate boundary conditions (it will become clear what this means later).

Then I can interpret my cylindrical function as a functional of the field configuration $\phi(x)$ as follows:

$$
\Psi[\phi] = \psi \left( \underbrace{\int d^3 x e^{-i \vec{p}_1 \vec{x}} \phi(x)}_{f_1}, \underbrace{\int d^3 x e^{-i \vec{p}_2 \vec{x}} \phi(x)}_{f_2} \right).
$$

So in this way we can construct *some* functionals of $\phi$.

Moreover, we actually have a well-defined inner product on cylindrical functions. Let's construct it in two steps.

Step 1: for two cylindrical functions with the same support sets. This can be constructed by first constructing a metric on the set of modes. For the plane waves, this is simply

$$(\Psi_1, \Psi_2) = \int d^2 f \; \psi_1^{*}(f_1, f_2) \psi_2(f_1, f_2). $$

Step 2: for arbitrary cylindrical functions. Key observation is that we can always trivially extend the support of a cylindrical function by adding more modes, and replacing $\psi$ with a function that doesn't depend on the new modes. So we can extend both cylindrical functions to the union of the sets of their modes and use the definition from step 1.

The caveat here is that the integral will diverge, because we're integrating a function constant in some $f_n$ over $-\infty < f_n < \infty$. We didn't have this in Loop Quantization because there the mode was valued in the compact Lie group $SU(2)$, so the integral would converge. Usually to resolve this, a cut-off on the field values is introduced: $-\Lambda < f_n < \Lambda$, and additionally, we have to normalize the measure $df_n$ such that the full integral is equal to exactly 1 (this is because we don't want extending cylindrical functions by other arbitrary modes to change the inner product).

The actual conceptual difference between Loop Quantization and Polymer Quantization comes from the lack of diffeomorphism invariance for the latter. In both situations you end up with an uncountably inifinite dimensional space of cylindrical functions, however, for Loop Quantization, something beautiful and LQG-specific happens: gauging away spatial diffeomorphisms leaves you with a separable Hilbert space of diffeomorphism-invariant states. This is crucial for the construction of the physical interpretation, geometric observables, and everything that is LQG really.

In contrast, Polymer quantization never gets to this point. It is an attempt to build physics on this non-separable (read, with an uncountable basis) space of cylindrical functions in unconventional ways.

Polymer Quantized models aren't actually Quantum Field Theory, which is very evident because of many things such as the lack of strong continuity in the Poincare group representation, etc.

However, it has been showed that certain Polymer Quantization models can *approximate* real QFT. This is exciting because this could mean that in principle, it could be possible to construct a definition of some QFT models by taking carefully analyzed limits of polymer models and proving certain properties. Before you get your hopes up, this may, and most likely will, do be honest, be not easier than using Hamiltonian or Euclidean or any other methods that still haven't worked for those models.

Comment: So to clarify if i understood: i have similar non separable hilbert spaces, but the polymer one has a hand-made cutoff and the states are not diffeom. invariant. So if for example i wanna apply both to a gravity context, let's say cosmology, in the polymer one i have to give up on diffeomorphism invariance of my states, right? While in LQG models i have it built directly into the hilbert space

Comment: @LolloBoldo loop quantization is a multi step process. At step 1, you operate with a non separable Banach space. At step 2, you solve the diffeomorphism constraint to get a separable Hilbert space. Polymer quantization can follow through step 1 but not step 2, because it’s applied to theories that are not diffeomorphism invariant. You can’t apply polymer to gravity/cosmology directly, LQC is a set of approximation techniques. Polymer was simply inspired by it.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant hahahaha, sorry for my bad expression skills. Could i ask you a couple questions in private? From other posts you seem like someone involved in the LQG field

Comment: @LolloBoldo privately might not be a good idea, but if you have questions about LQG, feel free to post them on this site and ping me.

Comment: It is more of a personal one. My issue is if a master thesis on applications of polymer quantization applied to gravity (not strictly cosmo) could lead me to a phd on LQG in the future, since polymer is the best my university has to offer about this field, unfortunately